# How to make a servo sweep from 0 to 180 on press of a button on PS2 controller? (without delay)

Tags: arduino-mega

I am working on a project that requires the servo to make a complete sweep once on pressing a button say r2 on the pS2 controller. I am using the Arduino Mega 2560,a PS2 controller clone, Bill porter's Ps2x library.

I have figured out a way to do so by adding a delay to the code but when the delay is used I can't use other parts of my project. What should I do?

```
int pos = 0;    // variable to store the servo position
int button = 2;  // The button will be on Pin 7
void setup()
{
myservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
pinMode(pos, OUTPUT);
pinMode(button, INPUT);
digitalWrite (button, LOW);
}

void loop()
{
if(ps2x.ButtonPressed(PSB_RED)) 

for(pos = 0; pos < 90; pos += 90)  // goes from 0 degrees to 90 degrees
{                                  // in steps of  degree
 myservo.write(pos);              

}
  if(ps2x.ButtonReleased(PSB_RED)) 

 for(pos = 90; pos>=90; pos-=90)    
 {                                
myservo.write(pos);              
delay(50);                             // waits 50ms for the servo to reach the position
```

Comment: What should you do? Well, at first you can simplify the answerer's task by actually posting the code you are using, so everybody can check and suggest you the modifications..

Comment: You need to look at interrupts.  Rather than delay you should keep looping until the next time to do something occurs.

Comment: yes interrupts could be be used but i have 5 motors , 2 stepper motors to control excluding the servos. wont interrupts make the code more complex?An example would really help.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the code, if you have a good understanding of how it works it shouldn't be too difficult to implement, but you would multitasking it by creating several objects that use a central time value. It should all be here, if you follow them and read them they can explain better than I: https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-tasking-the-arduino-part-1/overview

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot but , i am using an approach similar to the one described here http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/AvoidDelay